# Way to quickly check if string is XML or JSON in C#

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net

I'm using C# in a console app and I need a quick way to check if a string being returned from another service is XML or JSON.

I know if it was just XML, I could check it against a schema, or if it was just JSON I could try to parse it with JSON.Net, but is there a quicker way - maybe using build in .Net functions - just to tell which it is before then going on to process it?

Comment: Do you care about error handling if it's neither?

Comment: No the service returning the data will always return one or the other.

Comment: For JSON see [How to make sure that string is Valid JSON using JSON.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14977915)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Very simple:

1. Valid JSON starts always with '{' or '['
2. Valid XML starts always with '<'

I'm talking about non-space data.

Comment: Sounds good to me, unless anyone can point out any exceptions?

Comment: @finoutlook - just take a look on specifications. For JSON it is explicitly stated that valid JSON starts with one of these two characters and for XML - you can read the formal grammar specifications. You'll see that it must start with `<`...

Comment: Yeah I have to trust its a valid response from the server, so you're right it should meet the spec exactly.

Comment: If you are getting strings from a server and it might be JSON or it might be something else, this is not completely valid. What if it sends back another string wrapped in {} or <>?

Comment: I don't understand why this is marked as the correct answer, all this does is confirm that the string COULD be JSON or XML.  But is the string {{{{{ Valid JSON? No...

Comment: @JLo because the question didn't related to validation of XML or JSON but rather distinguishing between two in fastest way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the word "null" alone is valid JSON. That might be the only exception.

Answer (score 36):

```
public static bool IsJson(this string input){
    input = input.Trim();
    return input.StartsWith("{") && input.EndsWith("}") 
           || input.StartsWith("[") && input.EndsWith("]");
}
```

it's a bit dirty but simple and quick

It is essentially enough to test the first character. Testing the last is a very rude way of testing well formedness. It doesn't guarantee it it simply heightens the chance that it is well formed.

If you wanted a more robust version you could take advantage of the short circuiting of if's to only evaluate well-formedness if the initial check is good. The below code relies on JSON.net

```
public static bool IsJson(this string input){
    input = input.Trim();
    Predicate IsWellFormed = () => {
             try {
                JToken.Parse(input);
             } catch {
                return false;
             }
             return true;
    }
    return (input.StartsWith("{") && input.EndsWith("}") 
            || input.StartsWith("[") && input.EndsWith("]"))
           && IsWellFormed()
}
```

Comment: I went with something similar, but only checking the beginning of the string - so just `TrimStart()` and `StartsWith()`

Answer (score 2):

Thought I'd throw my solution in here too...

```
if (jsonData.Trim().Substring(0, 1).IndexOfAny(new[] {'[', '{'}) != 0)
     throw new Exception("The source file must be in JSON format");
```

or an extension...

```
public static bool IsJson(this string jsonData)
{
     return jsonData.Trim().Substring(0, 1).IndexOfAny(new[] { '[', '{' }) == 0;
}
```

usage:

```
if (!jsonData.IsJson())
     throw new Exception("The source file must be in JSON format");
```

Comment: instead of `.Trim().Substring(0,1)` you could simply do `.Trim()[0]`

Comment: Never throw Exception... throw a framework derived exception type or your own custom derived exception.

Answer (score 0):

The answers are nice, but I think you all forget the end of the JSON. Here is a good example that your methods wouldn't catch, and it will throw an exception when the parser tries to parse the JSON.

```
{
    "positions": 
    [
        {
            "object": "position",
            "powerState": "1",
            "time": "72796",
            "place": "1",
            "clientId": ""
    ]
}
```

As you can see, it starts with `{` and ends with `}`, in the second hand starts with `[` and ends with `]`, but someone forgot to close the 3rd `{`. This generates an error in the JSON parser.

I would say a more secure method is to check the beginning and the end for `{[` that we find.

This doesn't happen often, but some people still handcraft their own JSON and forget some parts... Don't trust external data!

I hope it helps.

Comment: sure but the the OP is only asking about a quick way to decide if it is XML or JSON, not if it is a valid XML or JSON string

Comment: OP states that he wants a way to test it before processing it. You can't no if it's valid until you have processed it

Answer (score 0):

Check the `HttpContentHeaders.ContentType` property in of the returned `HttpResponseMessage` - [HttpContentHeaders.ContentType Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders.contenttype?view=netcore-2.2#System_Net_Http_Headers_HttpContentHeaders_ContentType).  You'll see something like `application/json; charset=utf-8`, `text/json; charset=utf-8`, `text/xml; charset=utf-8`. It returns a `MediaTypeHeaderValue` instance you can examine. In your case, you would look at the [MediaTypeHeaderValue.SubType Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.net.http.headers.mediatypeheadervalue.subtype?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Net_Http_Headers_MediaTypeHeaderValue_SubType) This is what I use to make sure I parse and validate accordingly.

This is the safest and most accurate way.  Unless of course you have an API that is returning xml or json as a string.

If you just had the `Content-Type` value as a string, you could use 
 [MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.mediatypeheadervalue.parse?view=netcore-2.2) to help parse the `Content-Type` string.

The `Content-Type` property is defined as part the HTTP Spec and details are here: [Content-Type [MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)