# Is there a Json Schema Validator plugin for C#?

Tags: c#, json, nunit

I need to validate JSON against a schema like:

```
bool isValid = SomeJsonSchemaValidator(responseContentInJsonFormat, jsonSchema);
```

Does anyone know of a .Net Nuget package or something that can do this?
I know POSTMAN uses TinyValidator.  But I need to do this from C# NUnit Tests.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977848/how-to-make-sure-that-string-is-valid-json-using-json-net

Comment: no library needed. Just use DataContractJavascriptSerializer and mark all properties as required

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `Json.NET` :

```
string schemaJson = @"{
  'description': 'A person',
  'type': 'object',
  'properties':
  {
    'name': {'type':'string'},
    'hobbies': {
      'type': 'array',
      'items': {'type':'string'}
    }
  }
}";

JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaJson);

JObject person = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'name': 'James',
  'hobbies': ['.NET', 'Blogging', 'Reading', 'Xbox', 'LOLCATS']
}");

bool valid = person.IsValid(schema);
```

Use this if you need see the error messages:

```
JObject person = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'name': null,
  'hobbies': ['Invalid content', 0.123456789]
}");

IList<string> messages;
bool valid = person.IsValid(schema, out messages);
// false
// Invalid type. Expected String but got Null. Line 2, position 21.
// Invalid type. Expected String but got Float. Line 3, position 51.
```

Source: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm