# Correct way to handle google json requests and handle errors

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using rest api to get a list of places from a given location using google maps but i'm having some issues .

Main Issue : While the response is ok most of the time , sometimes i get a wrongly formatted json or status="Not Ok" which cause my app to crash :

Is there a way to test for the status & validity of the json before deserializing to prevent crashes or other way ?

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

from this line :

```
place = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Places>(content,settings);
```

Secondary issue : I'm not sure what is the best way to deal with the page token returned and how to use it for recurring queries

Code for getting the json ( The try-catch does nothing - app still crashes)

```
public async Task<Places> recurNearbyPlacesRequest(int radius , string pageToken)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            Places place = null;

            string testurl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=45.498358,-73.4721847&radius=2000&pagetoken={0}&key={1}";

            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(testurl, pageToken , Constants.google_maps_key));

            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
            };

            try
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);


                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


                    place = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Places>(content,settings);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception E) { }


            return place;

        }
```

Error Json that causes crash :

```
{
   "error_message" : "The provided API key is invalid.",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}


{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

Places Class :

```
//JsontoC#

public class Location
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Northeast
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Southwest
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Viewport
{
    public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
    public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
}

public class Geometry
{
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public Viewport viewport { get; set; }
}

public class OpeningHours
{
    public bool open_now { get; set; }
    public List<object> weekday_text { get; set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    public int height { get; set; }
    public List<string> html_attributions { get; set; }
    public string photo_reference { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public OpeningHours opening_hours { get; set; }
    public List<Photo> photos { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public double rating { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public string scope { get; set; }
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
    public string vicinity { get; set; }
    public int? price_level { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<object> html_attributions { get; set; }
    public string next_page_token { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your asking too many questions here. Ask one question at a time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make sure that string is Valid JSON using JSON.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977848/how-to-make-sure-that-string-is-valid-json-using-json-net)

Comment: The try/catch should catch the exception. It probably crashes because you return null in that case and you're trying to access that in a different place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)