# Json.net sayes that json string is valid, but it's not

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am trying to pars json string:

```
{"name":,"age":30,"car":null}
```

First problem occurs when I parse json string into token.

```
JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);
```

After pasing json string json token has additional curly bracers.

```
{{"name":,"age":30,"car":null}}
```

Could you tell me why?

Next problem occurs when I try yo deserialize json string into .net object.

JToken.Parse() adds undefined to the name property:

```
{{"name": undefined,"age":30,"car":null}}
```

And deserialization fails. I expect that it will add null to the name property so json string can be converted to the .net object without exception. But, it doesn't and I am getting exception:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: u. Path 'name', line 2, position 11.'
```

How can I successfully parse such json string so it could be safely converted to the .net object?

Here is class structure for json string:

```
public class User
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public object car { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `{"name":,"age":30,"car":null}` is not valid json - you cannot have a key without a value as shown (`"name"`).  From that point you're likely hitting some edge cases in json.net that should otherwise be erroring out.

Comment: How could I validate this json to know in code that its invalid?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977848/how-to-make-sure-that-string-is-valid-json-using-json-net this should your problem

Comment: @MrgGek IMO, the `JsonReaderException` is how you know its invalid.

Comment: As for double curlies, where does it add them? In the debugger viewing the object? That’s just presentation, nothing more. Elsewhere? Please edit and clarify

Comment: Yes, in the debugger. Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: What version of Json.NET are you using?

Comment: latest version on nuget