# FromJson string to List

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core

my jsonResult is always have 1+ Invoice (class),
If it has 1 Invoice it gives error.

How can I change fromJson  <List to have a only 1 class.

If jsonResult has more than 1 Invoice -- no error
If jsonResult = 1 Invoice gives error. How can I fix it.

```
string jsonResult = (await GenericHttpClient.ExecuteAsync(requestModel)).Content;

 try
 {                

  return jsonResult.FromJson<List<Invoice>>();

 }
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977848/how-to-make-sure-that-string-is-valid-json-using-json-net will help, but you can use simple solution : check if ``jsonResult`` is not start with `[` and update the json like : `jsonResult = $"[{jsonResult }]"`

Comment: What JsonDeserialiser are you using? Json.NET or System.Text.Json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version for `System.Text.Json`:

```
public static List<int> GetValues(string json)
{
    using JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
    if (doc.RootElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array)
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<int>>(json);
    }
    else
    {
        return new List<int>(){ JsonSerializer.Deserialize<int>(json) };
    }
}
```

```
var a = GetValues("[1,2,3]"); // List with 3 elements: 1,2,3
var b = GetValues("1");       // List with 1 element: 1
```